# Angular 14, How to Remove polyfills.js Errors

Tags: node.js, angular, polyfills

I am getting the following error, both in production and dev/serve environments:
[image]

The error is received when the API server is returning 500 error code (which is fine), I was looking to get rid of these error but couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?